# Uglifier - NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, uglifier

I have been facing the `NoMethodError: undefined method start_with?' for nil:NilClass` error while precompiling assets in production.

This seems to be an issue with `uglifier` and I am using the following gems:

> rails (5.2.2)
>
> uglifier (4.1.9)
>
> sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
>
> therubyracer (0.12.3)

Log trace:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.36s.
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:225:in `error_message'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
```

I checked the similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/137) but adding `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true, compress: { unused: false })` to `config/environments/production.rb` did not resolve the issue.

Any lead to resolve the issue would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a longer log trace? Are you sure you don't have that method error somewhere in your application?

Comment: @Clara : No this method doesn't belong to my application. As the above trace suggests, that method exists in Uglifier gem.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, problem comes from the gem.
I had to remove `uglifier` from my gemfile, as well as comment out the line `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` from my `config/production.rb`

Answer (score 1):

here is an issue https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/137

always check "issues" on gems page

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
I would request you to read the question fully as I have mentioned this link already in the question where it says `I checked the similar issue reported here...`

Comment: ok, other solution, fork and clone uglifier gem. Connect it in Gemfile, using gem "uglifier", github: '.....'. And put a change here https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/lib/uglifier.rb#L225 and check if object is nil or not

Comment: yeah , result hash looks like this: `{ "error" => {} }`